# Set ticks offset in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I need to draw a chart using Chart.js and set minimal and maximal value for X axis (type: linear). But that values can be not "nice" (not a multiple of ten, for example), but I want ticks to be "nice".

I think there must be a way to set ticks offset to first "nice" value, or set minimal and maximal ticks values independently of minimal and maximal axis values, but I can't find how to do it in documentation. How can I do that?